A Crime anthology movie
I'm looking for a crime based movie, which was made after 2005. I may have watched it in 2007 or afterwards. It could be either a series of true crime/horror anthologies like Masters of Horror, or a short part of a crime based movie. Unfortunately, I was only able to watch this part (about 30 mins):
What I remember from the plot:

A middle aged woman comes home at night. Her house is two-storeyed and has a garden. 
It's dark and nobody is at home. When she enters, an unknown man, who was hiding behind the door, attacks her. 
Her neighbours hear noise and call 911.
A police officer, who was patrolling, answers the 911 call on the police radio. He comes to the woman's door and rings. 
The unknown man threatens the woman who came home with a gun and says:
"Act normal or I'll kill you".
She acts normal and tells the cop:
"Everything's fine officer."
The police officer says:
"Okay. Goodnight, ma'am." 
But he gets suspicious and goes around the back. Then, he enters the house through an open window. He sees the man and tries to catch him. 
They get into a fight and when it's over he kills him or knocks him out.


Some other details; 

Language: Probably English
Location: Most likely USA or UK
Release year: Between 2005-2013
Genre: Horror, crime

Details of the characters:

Woman: 28-38 aged, white, middle sized, single 
Intruder: Middle aged, white 
Police officer: 28-38 aged, white, clumsy and funny. He looked like the character 'Dewey' from Scream.


A bit similar to a scene in "Panic Room"

@madmada Yes, but think about the one with fewer dialogue and less dramatic.

Sounds a little like Sleeping with the Enemy but it's not a cop that comes to the door, it's her new boyfriend. (and is from 1991)

@TimS. I watched that movie. It's kinda similar but different. The key is she was alone and there was nobody at the house. She had just arrived at her home and she hadn't seen the intruder until opened the door. The cop/boyfriend and the release year also differs like u said.

Why probably English as the language? Might it have been a different language, and if so which one?

@Broneironaut It may be German and French as well but these are minor possibilities. I‘ve watched it dubbed in my language.

I've heard/seen a lot of age ranges described as "old", not always seriously; but this is the first time I've seen ~28-38 described as "middle aged".

@N.Presley There’s always a first time, for everything ;)
